# Collect html form data and send as a json payload to an api

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, api

I want to collect the HTML form data and send it a JSON payload to the API. I have tried with my code below. I pushed the api in the action on the form but it gave me an error. I tried doing it with javascript and it's not working either.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitform").click(function(e) {
    var MyForm = JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeJSON());
    console.log(MyForm);
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://test.theteller.net/checkout/initiate",
      type: "POST",
      data: MyForm,

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="merchant_id">merchant_id</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="merchant_id" placeholder="merchant_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="transaction_id">transaction_id</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="transaction_id">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="desc">desc</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="amount">amount</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="redirect_url">redirect_url</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="redirect_url">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="API_Key">API_Key</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="API_Key">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="apiuser">apiuser</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apiuser">

    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="submitform" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you add the jQuery library to your page?

Comment: Also `$("#submitform").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault();`  IS MANDATORY